# WPF Listview Access to SelectedItem and subitems

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, selecteditem

Ok, I am having more problems with my C# WPF ListView control. Here it is in all its glory:

```
<Window x:Class="ebook.SearchResults" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"Title="ISBNListView" Height="503" Width="1004">
<Grid>
    <ListView Name="listView1" Margin"22,30,33,28" MouseDoubleClick="getSelectedItem" >

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="ISBN" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ISBN}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Author" Width="350" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Author}" />
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

I am filling the listView with the following:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(GlobalVars.docPath + "\\tempSearchResults.xml");
        var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("Book")
                    select new
                    {
                        ISBN = item.Element("ISBN").Value,
                        Title = item.Element("Title").Value,
                        AuthTexts = item.Element("Author").Value
                    };
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(new { ISBN = item.ISBN, Title = item.Title, Author = item.AuthTexts });
        }
```

I am having a devil of a time retrieving data from a row when it is double clicked.
The DoubleClick does popup a message box with all the data in the row, I just cannot seem to get only one subitem or cell's data. Say a row has ISBN: 1234567  Title: Hurrr Author: Waldo, how do I just retrieve the ISBN or just the title?

```
private void getSelectedItem(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(listView1.SelectedItems[0].ToString());
    }
```

Still new to C# and .Net and banging my head against the wall. I figure this should be rather simple.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`listView1.SelectedItems[0]` returns an `object`. You first need to **cast it to its specific type** before you can access its members. For casting you need to know the name of the class to cast to, but you're adding instances of an **anonymous class** (= has no name) to your ListView.

Solution: Define a class (e.g., `Book`) with ISBN, Title and Author properties and add instances of `Book` to the ListView. Then you can do the necessary cast:

```
private void getSelectedItem(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Book book = (Book)listView1.SelectedItems[0];
    System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(book.ISBN);
}
```

---

Don't forget to add instances if `Book` to the ListView instead of instances of an anonymous type:

```
var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("Book")
            select new Book                                   //  <---
            {
                ISBN = (string)item.Element("ISBN"),
                Title = (string)item.Element("Title"),
                Author = (string)item.Element("Author"),
            };

foreach (var item in items)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I added a class book as:

public class Book
{
  public string ISBN { get; set; }
  public string Title { get; set; }
  public string Author { get; set; }
}

When I double click on a row I get the following error on the Book instantiation line you provided:
   Unable to cast object of type '<>F_AnonymousType1'3[System.String, System.String, System.String]' to type 'Book'

Comment: You're still adding instances of an anonymous type to your ListView. Answer updated.

Comment: Also `Book book = (Book)listView1.SelectedItems[0];` can be used as `var book = (Book)listView1.SelectedItems[0];`

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to be more clear with the code

Getting selected item

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="TheList" SelectionChanged="TheList_SelectionChanged"/>
```

CS:

```
private void TheList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyItemClass SelectedItem = (MyItemClass)TheList.SelectedItem;

    if (SelectedItem != null)
        MessageBox.Show(SelectedItem.Title);
}
```

And for double clicking item (almost the same)

XAML:

```
<ListView Name="TheList" MouseDoubleClick="TheList_MouseDoubleClick"/>
```

CS:

```
private void TheList_SelectionChanged(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MyItemClass SelectedItem = (MyItemClass)TheList.SelectedItem;

    if (SelectedItem != null)
        MessageBox.Show(SelectedItem.Title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var items = from item in xdoc.Descendants("Book")
            select new Book()                                   //  <---
            {
                ISBN = (string)item.Element("ISBN"),
                Title = (string)item.Element("Title"),
                Author = (string)item.Element("Author"),
            };

foreach (var item in items)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

I have got an issue with code above, once I use it, my listView did not list any of those values. I do not know if that will help you or if that is correct but after a few tests I added () after "select new Book" and then ListView could show all fields correctly for me.