# How to get selected ListView Item?

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [WPF Listview Access to SelectedItem and subitems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402878/wpf-listview-access-to-selecteditem-and-subitems)

I have a listview in my xaml and I want to get the selected item in the code-behind. In fact I would like to get the content of the item (which is an object). I've tried to do MyListView.SelectedItems[0] but it doesn't work, I have "accessor get or set expected".

Answer (score 4):

I guess you should use [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx) not [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems.aspx):

> This property is meant to be used when SelectionMode does not equal
>   Single. If the selection mode is Single the correct property to use is
>   SelectedItem.

Answer (score 3):

You can try with this code

```
var selectedItems = MyListView.SelectedItems;
foreach (ListViewItem selectedItem in selectedItems)
{
   //Treatment
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you using it? It should be `MyListView.SelectedItems[0]`.

```
MyObject foo = (MyObject)MyListView.SelectedItems[0];
```

You should probably add some checks if `SelectedItems` contains actual items and the `SelectedItem` object is indeed a `MyObject`, but you get the idea.

Also if you select a single item there is `SelectedItem`, I think.